# How do I limit number of rows in the admin form in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

down vote
favorite
I have following code in my Form.php

```
$fieldset->addField('name', 'textarea', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Name'),
    'class' => 'required-entry',
    'required' => true,
    'name' => 'name',
));
```

I want to restrict the number of rows to display it like a single row, the code: 'rows' => 1 doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to change 'textarea' for 'text'.